# Plot graphs using city names instead of Latitude and Longitude

Tags: python, google-maps, maps, data-visualization, tweepy

I am extracting tweets data from Twitter and classifying the tweets in 3 type of score as "positive", "negative" or "neutral". I want to map the location of user on the world map and notify each location color by its type i.e. "Positive" (green color), "negative" (red color) or "neutral" (yellow color). Twitter returns user location as:
"location": "Northampton, England"
"score": "positive"

How can I plot this data on maps by using location's country, city and score?
is there ant JavaScript library?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter also returns the Country and Country code in 'place' attribute. You can use the country code and [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/choropleth-maps/) to create a beautiful choropleth map. Plotly will classify your data per country code on the map.The only problem is that plotly uses 3-digit country codes and twitter 2-digit codes so you are going to have to map those using data found [here](https://github.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/blob/master/all/all.csv)

Plotly also has plenty of features to display dynamically the score, country name and whateve you need. I have done this before in python. There is also a javascript library available.Enjoy!